# AS3 Menu not detecting clicks

Tags: actionscript-3, button, switch-statement

I've got some buttons that just navigate around the timeline. I was trying to make a switch statement that would save me some time writing code. This is what I've come up with, but it doesn't work. The buttons each have a rollover function as well that works just fine. The traces are in there for debugging.

```
for (var a=0; a<mainButtons.length; a++){
mainButtons[a].buttonMode = true;
mainButtons[a].addEventListener(rolled, hideDbases);
mainButtons[a].addEventListener(clicked, switchView);
}

function switchView(e:Event):void {
    switch (e.target.name) {
        case "count_btn":
            gotoAndPlay(4);
            trace("count");
        break;
        case "order_btn":
            gotoAndPlay(5);
            trace("order");
        break;
        case "admin_btn":
            gotoAndPlay(6);
            trace("admin");
        break;
        case "serve_btn":
            gotoAndPlay(7);
            trace("service");
        break;
        case "video_btn":
            gotoAndPlay(8);
            trace("video");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get the traces at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the I needed to give the graphic in the back the same instance name as the main movieclip. The button I made was a gradient, a text box and an icon. All three elements were movieclips themselves and then made into one main movieclip. So if the parent's instance was called count_btn then I had to also call the gradient background's instance count_btn. Don't really know why but the problem is solved.